# PDO connection error when using symfony and MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, mamp

Getting an PDO error when trying to do
 `php symfony doctrine:insert-sql`

The error I get:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): [2002] Connection refused (trying to connect via tcp://127.0.0.1:3306) in /Users/johannes/Programmering/PHP/htdocs/symfony/sfprojects/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 470
```

databases.yml

```
    all:
    doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=jobeet;
      username: root
      password: root
```

Doing a  `mysql -u root -p jobeet`  with "root" as password gives me access, so no problem there. And yes, the mysql that I run is MAMP's.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: do you really need this part ? `;mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

Comment: i get the error with or without

Comment: wanted to say that changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 fixed it (i'm using xampp)

Comment: Just to add for anyone else that may run into this issue. If you are running a non-standard port like MAMP does (8889) for MySQL you will still run into this issue if you even use 127.0.0.1. Running on the standard port 3306 fixed it. If I find where to change this I'll post back. But I was using CodeIgniter 2 and Doctrine 2, so it's a little more complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MAMP by default doesn't allow TCP connections. You can either turn it on or use sockets.

Changing your dsn as @Tom suggests should fix your issues. Weird as it is but using **localhost** instead of **127.0.0.1** makes that mysql connects through sockets.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html :

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host
>   name localhost specially, in a way
>   that is likely different from what you
>   expect compared to other network-based
>   programs. For connections to
>   localhost, MySQL programs attempt to
>   connect to the local server by using a
>   Unix socket file. This occurs even if
>   a --port or -P option is given to
>   specify a port number. To ensure that
>   the client makes a TCP/IP connection
>   to the local server, use --host or -h
>   to specify a host name value of
>   127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also
>   specify the connection protocol
>   explicitly, even for localhost, by
>   using the --protocol=TCP option.

Comment: Well, I think both my answer and @Tom's are valid. It's just you need to do some additional configuration to MAMP. You got a "no such file or directory' message because MAMP saves socket in a non default location.

Comment: nice, using `localhost` instead of 127.0.0.1 did the trick; no need to open up access outside of local as @James suggests

Answer (score 13):

**MAMP PRO 2.x**
I was able to solve this and many similar issues by simply unchecking "Allow local access only" in the MySQL prefs on the MAMP control panel.

[image]

**MAMP PRO 3.x**
As stated by [Kendrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1022493/kendrick):
[image]

Comment: MAMP 3.0 Looks a little different but essentially the same fix. SELECT "Allow network access to MySQL" >> "Only from this mac"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when attempting to build my tables in Symfony and using MAMP. I fixed the issue by changing my dsn line, in the databases.yml file, to the following:

```
dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jobeet;unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks right. Here would be the exact equivalent from a working databases.yml I'm using, in case it's of any use:

```
dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jobeet'
```

Comment: changing the host from 127.0.0.1 to localhost, gives me this error <code> No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///var/mysql/mysql.sock) </code>