# Setting up Laravel on a Mac php artisan migrate error: No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mmap

1. Pulled a perfectly working laravel project from a git into a mac running MAMP. Project ran perfectly on a linux machine.
2. composer install
3. php artisan migrate, got the following error:

   ```
   [PDOException]                                    
   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
   ```

NB:
php -v is 5.5 and mysql -v is 5.5 from the terminal
Here is part of my config/database.php

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'essays',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

I tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 with no avail. Kindly help..

**Edit:**
I added these three lines in my php.ini

```
mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

mysqli.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

pdo_mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I also added this symlink:

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
cd /var/mysql && sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But that didnt solve. I also pulled a fresh new laravel project from git and ran into the same error after `composer install` then `php artisan migrate`

```
 [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

The mac version is 10.7.4

Comment: This has been asked before, and searching for your error message gives a lot of questions and possible answers. Try them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001592/what-would-cause-intermittent-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-e

Comment: Thanks for the edit and info. I had done some thorough research before, added the php.ini lines and the symlink at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000 But That didnt solve. I also pulled a fresh new laravel project from git and ran into the same error after composer install then php artisan migrate

Comment: Check the edits in my question....

Comment: Where is the `config/database.php` file?

Comment: If you are using homestead/vagrant, make sure that you have `ssh`d into the server. And not running it from the outside.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

If you are using MAMP be sure to add the `unix_socket` key with a value of the path that the `mysql.sock` resides in MAMP.

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
        'database'  => 'database',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => 'root',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Comment: This worked for me. Everything was great until I brilliantly decided I wanted to install/configure PHP via Homebrew on Mavericks. Needless to say I've been using an alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/../pathto/php' for the last 2 weeks.  Not sure I feel good about this fix, but it got me back up and running without the alias. Thanks!

Comment: Same here i ve used homebrew too so the solution was to add the unix_socket path in `config/local/database.php` file.

Comment: I added that line, but got following error: `[PDOException]                                                    
  SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected` Any idea what issue is? I'm seeing that the key was updated in an `.env` file, not the `database.php` file. Not really sure if that has anything to do with it...

Comment: You can use this answer instead of adding the sockets. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12146144/662581

Comment: I can not find the `config/local/database.php` file. Where can I find it?

Comment: For xampp, you can use /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock.

Or mysql and do "status"

Comment: Where do I find the file to add this line/path?

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me adding this to `.env`:
`DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

Answer (score 23):

### Do not assume your unix_socket which would be different from one to another, try to find it.

First of all, **get your unix_socket location**.

```
$ mysql -uroot -p
```

Enter your mysql password and login your mysql server from command line.

```
mysql> show variables like '%sock%';
+---------------+---------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                                 |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+
| socket        | /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Your unix_soket could be diffrent.

Then you got 2 solution to solve your issue:

(1) Change your `config/database.php`

```
    'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'essays',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'root',
    'unix_socket'   => '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock', //Your sock got from above
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

(2) Change your php.ini, find your `php.ini` file from

```
<? phpinfo();
```

You maybe install many php with different version, so please don't assume your php.ini file location, get it from your 'phpinfo';

Change your php.ini:

```
mysql.default_socket = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock

mysqli.default_socket = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock

pdo_mysql.default_socket = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
```

Then restart your apache or php-fpm.

Comment: I switched from MAMP's own mysql to mariadb and your solution was the only solution that worked.

Comment: the php.ini solution works efficiently if you work in many project. you don't need to change database.php file in each project, just edit the php.ini file. thanks for the solution

Answer (score 16):

Had the same problem, but it's working for me now.

If anybody is still having problems, try this:

- Make sure your `bootstrap/start.php` contains your actual hostname, not the name of your virtual host. Enter `hostname` in the terminal to get your hostname. As it's an array I believe you can enter both your hostname and the name(s) of your virtual host(s).
- Replace "localhost" with "127.0.0.1".

Comment: replacing "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" worked for me. :-)

Answer (score 14):

If you are using XAMPP, the solution is:

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'      => 'mysql',
        'unix_socket' => '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
        'host'        => 'localhost'
)
```

Answer (score 9):

This works for me in Laravel 5.0, change the **DB_HOST=127.0.0.1:33060** in .env file.

Others answers don't work...

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Laravel 5.1.11 version + MAC + MAMPP

you  have to add  "Unix_socket " in  file "yourapp"/app/config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

Unix_socket param was added to above  mysql config drive.

Comment: but the socket file is not located for me .

Comment: what is your mampp version

Answer (score 5):

For Laravel 5.0+ change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in your .env file as well before you go playing around with Unix Sockets etc - this worked for me.

Noobs beware: For anyone using Laravel 5 and using older learning material be aware that there was quite a marked shift in folder structure from previous versions though this seems to be for the better- check out this article https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-directory-structure-and-namespace

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to add the port number in the host key. In this case MAMP uses the 8889 by default:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost:8889',
    'database'  => 'essays',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'root',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```