# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a laravel project on OS X.  I installed MySql with homebrew.  I tried googling around for why I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

when I try to do

```
php artisan migrate
```

And most of the answers I see say php and MySql cannot communicate to each other.  I've been trying to see where I went wrong since I think I followed previous posts about it, and it still doesn't work.  I created a page that just does this:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

And I see these types of things:
In the Configure area, I see:

```
'--with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-zend-signals' '--enable-dtrace'
```

loaded configuration file:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini
```

If I `ls /tmp`, I do see mysql.sock.

In that php.ini file, I set these lines:
pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock

And then in /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.16/my.cnf, I added the following line:

```
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I DID restart apache, as well as check mysql is running.  I haven't seen any other advice besides the php and mysql connection.  I think there are two versions of php on my system because when I installed mcrypt or something else I can't remember, it installed another php version.  But when I do look at the output of phpinfo, I'm editing the appropriate php.ini file.  I didn't know if there is another piece I am missing.  Any thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: i just got this error by trying to enable the "mysql general query log" to debug some doctrine/php code i'm working with.

Comment: I just had to enable mysqli.so extension in php.ini

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching, I found this post:

[Setting up Laravel on a Mac php artisan migrate error: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475762/settting-up-laravel-on-a-mac-php-artisan-migrate-error-no-such-file-or-director)

Once I added

```
'unix_socket' => '/tmp/mysql.sock’,
```

to my database.php in the mysql array, it worked.  Not sure exactly why that works, but it does.

Answer (score 50):

I had a similar error. I am using MAMP and what solved my issue was:

1. creating a symbolic link in: /var/mysql (create the directory if it does not exist)
2. cd /var/mysql && sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: This fixed it for me. I'm not using MAMP though, so it was cd /var/mysql && sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: @MikeRentas You just saved me some sanity... Every reference i see is using MAMP and I just set up everything manually -- yours was the only thing that worked, though i'm getting a permissions error now.

Comment: @MikeRentas Your particular solution worked great for me trying to set up a legacy Symfony 1.4 app on Mac OS X Yosemite. I had installed MariaDB via Homebrew, which I guess places the `mysql.sock` file in `/tmp`.

Comment: solved the problem for me, but can you explain why it works please?

Comment: @HappyCoder Thank you, this solved it for me on MAC OSX using MAMP

Comment: Thanks, this helped for me too.

Comment: Solved on Mac too, thanks.

Comment: ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock

Answer (score 10):

For users which are looking for a solution on XAMPP (Tested and worked on Mac OS X),

Open terminal and create a symbolic link :

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
cd /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Hello, i tried this but no luck, i get the error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`. I am using slim php framework, xampp on Mac OS. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: Try using "localhost" instead of a "127.0.0.1" or vice-versa when connecting to your DataBase to see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works with `localhost`. Then what should I do to make it work with `127.0.0.1` as well?

Comment: I don't know the slim php framework, but it might have something to do with your configuration file?

Comment: Worked like a charm - thanks. PS I used it in MAMP with the MAMP path.

Comment: when you say open terminal, should i open the terminal at any particular folder? should i be openning this at the folder of my laravel application?

Answer (score 7):

I found PHP on CentOS 6 built with `mysql.default_socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` yet for some reason `pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock`, which doesn't exist.  Building it using `--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` should force both to be the same.

Alternatively edit `php.ini` to contain:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

...or your correct socket location, of course.

Answer (score 5):

i fixed it like this.Just add a line. 
in laravel project
APP=>Config=>database.php
update the
Connections=>mysql
after strict add below line

```
'unix_socket' => "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

sample:-

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
            'unix_socket' => "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock"
        ],
```

Comment: I added to my .env 
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me out of nowhere, my app (Laravel) was working fine yesterday and dropped today with this error (SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory).

After checking that my config file had not been not corrupted, I connected to my control panel (I am using a VPS) and restarted MySQL server. That did the trick, everything is back online.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for Ampps user:
I had the same issue and I did a lot of searches but couldn't solve the issue until I looked at my MySql config file.
In my config file socket was in line 21 and the path was
"/Applications/AMPPS/var/mysql.sock"

In Ampps application click on MySql tab and then click on configuration button.

You can also find the config file in "/Applications/AMPPS/mysql/etc" folder

So simply I added 
'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/AMPPS/var/mysql.sock', 
to my database.php in mysql array and it's worked for me.
After host line. I have tested with localhost and 127.0.0.1 and both worked

Hopefully it's working for you too.