# Magento keep throwing SQLState no such file or directory error

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am running magento on VPS server with APC enabled, nginx reverse proxy and apache with MYSQL. But I keep getting this error on report folder and sometimes site is down due to that. Can you please guide me how can i fix it. There's no funny xml file inside app/etc/ as well. Thank you.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:48:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory";i:1;s:3103:"#0 /home/magen/public_html/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/magen/public_html/shop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(313): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/magen/public_html/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/magen/public_html/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/magen/public_html/shop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(490): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
#20 /home/magen/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/magen/public_html/shop/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:6:"/shop/";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/shop/index.php";}
```

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188026/sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @knightrider I'm experiencing the same on my live webshop sometimes when i cancel an order. Did you find any solution for the problem?