# Slim Application Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp, slim

I am programming an application by using the Slim Framework in PHP and MySQL. 
I am on Mac OS X and using XAMPP.

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25782795/1883256) but no luck.

In my phpmyadmin I have the root user's servers in the three modes:

1. %
2. linux
3. localhost

This is the code of configs to connect to the database:

```
'db'    =>  [
    'driver'    =>  'mysql',
    'host'      =>  '127.0.0.1',
    'name'      =>  'rl',
    'username'  =>  'root',
    'password'  =>  'the_password',
    'charset'   =>  'utf8mb4',
    'collation' =>  'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    =>  ''
],
```

Any ideas to fix this?

**FIXED**

I changed `127.0.0.1` for `localhost` and now it works!

Now the question is, how can i make it work by using `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Can you try to login using the command line or any other software?

Comment: Yeah, i tried this and decided to try `localhost` instead and now it works! But then how can i make it to work with `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Can you check [this](http://serverfault.com/a/544196/276936)?

Answer (score 0):

I had simmilar problem and the charset was wrong and it should be just utf8 like that:

```html
'db'    =>  [
    'driver'    =>  'mysql',
    'host'      =>  'localhost',
    'name'      =>  'rl',
    'username'  =>  'root',
    'password'  =>  'the_password',
    'charset'   =>  'utf8',
    'collation' =>  'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    =>  ''
],
```