# Laravel 5 php artisan migrate does not work

Tags: migration, laravel-5.1

Im using `Mac os x Yosemite 10.10`. I installed the lastest `laravel version 5.1`.
I set up Homestead and it has been running great. However, when I try to make a `MySQL` connection in my Laravel app, and am now experiencing errors when running php artisan migrate on my development machine. Following is the statement that I see when I run php artisan migrate.

> [PDOException]                                       SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2002] No such file or directory

How can I solve this problem? When I get into VM, mysql works fine. But I do not know how I can use php artisan migrate.
Thank you in advance.

Best

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up Laravel on a Mac php artisan migrate error: No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475762/setting-up-laravel-on-a-mac-php-artisan-migrate-error-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Hi. Since I'm using Homestead, the link you have offered is not working for me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: My mistake. Didn't see that .

Answer (score 2):

check mysql server is available or not and check database.php with proper sql driver
path for database.php

```
  project/config/database.php
```

check your .env file in project directory and check DB details

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your  .env file (root directory) and check twice your connections. ex:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=dbname
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```