# PDOException when trying to run php migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I tried to run `php artisan migrate` with laravel, I received the following error: ""

```
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

How do I resolve this issue? I've seen other stackoverflow posts such as [Laravel 5 php artisan migrate does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188509/laravel-5-php-artisan-migrate-does-not-work) with similar problems. However, they have a different error message while I have "Connection refused". Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you have set proper database username password in env file

Comment: you are trying with wrong database credential

Comment: Check your DB is running ? It looks DB server not running

Comment: If your DB credentials wrong then you might get `Access denied for user xxx@localhost.com`. Try to login to database with same credentials from terminal

Comment: Also try adding the port :
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/pdo-connection-refused-with-laravel-but-not-with-con-new-pdo

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395452/php-connection-failed-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure sql is running on your computer. Then check the .env file.