# How can you add back authentication to Laravel 5.1?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.1

Laravel 5 came out with a nice Auth scaffolding, which included all of the routes/controllers/views for registering and authenticating a users.  But I started using Laravel 5.1 recently, and noticed authentication is no longer built in.  How can I add it back?

Answer (score 7):

Laravel does already have documentation on [building authentication into your Laravel 5.1 app](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication).  However, I'll go through this in a bit more detail...

## Installing Laravel

First, make sure you have a fresh install of Laravel. Here is my tutorial on [Installing Laravel 5.1 on OSX with MAMP](http://martythomas.svbtle.com/creating-laravel-saas-bootstrap).

## Add Twitter Bootstrap

After [downloading bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) add the bootstrap.css file into the `public/css` directory.  (you may have to create the css directory.

Also copy over bootstrap's `fonts` directory into your app's `public` directory.

## Add Authentication Routes

Add the following routes to the `app/Http/routes.php` file.

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

// Password reset link request routes...
Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');

// Password reset routes...
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
```

## Add Authentication Views

First let's create a blade template to use for all of our other views.  We can do that by creating a `resources/views/auth/app.blade.php` file.  And copy/paste the code shown here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/resources/views/app.blade.php

Create a new `resources/views/auth` directory.   Within that directory,  create the following files.

- login.blade.php (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php)
- password.blade.php (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/resources/views/auth/password.blade.php)
- register.blade.php (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php)
- reset.blade.php (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/resources/views/auth/reset.blade.php)

For the "forgot password" email, create a `resources/views/emails` directory, and place the following file into it.

- password.blade.php (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.0/resources/views/emails/password.blade.php)

## Create Database & Tables

To make it so that we can actually register a new user and login, we'll have to create the proper database tables.  Fortunately, this is already available through migrations.

First, create a new database table, and define it's connection in the `.env`  file.

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
```

The trigger the migration with the following command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Since I'm using MAMP, I got this error when trying to migrate.

```
[PDOException]
```

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Solution was to [add the `unix_socket` key with a value of the path that the mysql.sock resides in MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475762/setting-up-laravel-on-a-mac-php-artisan-migrate-error-no-such-file-or-directory).

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
        'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
    ],
```

## Setup SMTP Server

Laravel 5.1 defaults to mailtrap.io.  First time I gave this a try, and it's actually quite easy!  First step is to [setup mailtrap.io account](https://mailtrap.io/).

Update **.env** file with SMTP settings (provided after signing up)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Update from address in **config/mail.php** file.

```
'from' => ['address' => 'noreply@test.com', 'name' => 'test'],
```

## Create Dashboard

Add dashboard routes

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'Dash\DashboardController@home');
```

Add dashboard controllers to `app/Http/Controllers/Dash/DashboardController.php`

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Dash\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function home(Request $request)
    {
        return view('dashboard/home');
    }
}
```

Note the use of `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`.  This is important since were using a different namespace for our dashboard.

And the view at `resources/views/dashboard/home.blade.php`:

```
   @extends('app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    You are logged in!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Update login redirects:

- Update `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated`

with:

```
return redirect('/dashboard');
```

Add to `Auth/PasswordController.php` and `Auth/AuthController.php` files.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
```

## Authenticate Dashboard

To restrict access to the dashboard to only those that are logged in, we can ddd the following to the Dashboard controller

```
public function __construct() 
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the docs as pointed by Marty Thomas you can also try to use this [package](https://github.com/bestmomo/scafold) for auth scaffolding.

Comment: Ya.. I gave this package a try as well.  I'm just a control freak and like to know exactly whats going on, and keep the controllers/views all organized in the same place.   But the package does work quite nicely.