# Installing Laravel 5.1 on OSX with MAMP

Tags: macos, laravel, mamp, laravel-5.1

I tried to install Laravel 5.1 on OSX Yosemite with MAMP, and ran across a couple of road blocks.  Specifically, I got the following error when trying to migrate the database.

```
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Comment: If you're using the default `sqlite` driver, just do `touch storage/database.sqlite` to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 33):

## 1) Install Composer

If you don't yet have composer installed, you will need to do that.  You can test weather you have composer installed by simply typing in the `composer` command into mac's [terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(OS_X)). You should see a list of available commands if composer is installed.

[image: Screen Shot 2015-08-17 at 1.34.05 PM.png]

If you don't yet have composer installed, you can see [Getting Started with Composer](http://martythomas.svbtle.com/getting-started-with-composer)

## 2) Install Laravel

Laravel has good documentation in [installing Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation).  I'll walk through exactly what steps I took to get Laravel up and running on OSX Yosemite.

Install via Laravel Installer.  Type the following into terminal.

```
cd ~/
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Add the composer executable to the Path environment, so to that the `laravel` executable can be found.

```
PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Install a fresh Laravel instance, and give it a name.  In our case we'll name the project **saas**.

```
laravel new saas
```

I'm using [MAMP PRO](https://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/) to run sites locally on my mac.  So I just need to create a new host in MAMP, and point it to the **saas/public** directory.

[image: laravel_mamp.png]

Then, visiting http://saas:8888 will show you Laravel's beautiful welcome screen.

[image: laravel5_1.png]

### 3) Create Database

I like to use [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-mysql) to manage my databases.  With Navicat for MySQL, I create a new local database.

Then, define it's connection in the `.env`  file.

```
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_DATABASE=saas
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
```

The trigger the migration with the following command:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Since I'm using MAMP, I got this error when trying to migrate.

```
[PDOException]
```

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Solution was to [add the `unix_socket` key with a value of the path that the mysql.sock resides in MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475762/setting-up-laravel-on-a-mac-php-artisan-migrate-error-no-such-file-or-directory).

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
        'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
    ],
```

### 4) Wrap-UP

Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable.  We'll do that with the following?

```
chmod -R 777 storage
chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache
```

Rename the environment file.

```
mv .env.example .env
```

### 5) PHP Path

Since were using MAMP, we have multiple version of PHP installed on our machine.  So if we try to run `php artisan`, we will be given an error.

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required
```

If you also receive that error, first check to see what version of PHP your using with MAMP.  You can check that through MAMP's Main Window > PHP.  In my case, were using version `5.6.10`.

Then we can edit our  `~/.bash_profile` file, by adding the following line:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin:$PATH
```

Restart terminal, and you should then be able to run the `php artisan` command.

And that's it.  Create something awesome!

Answer (score 5):

Adding local configuration to a file like config/database.php seemed wrong to me -- because any changes to it would also be uploaded to a Git repo.

Found this other solution that works fine with no code change:

```
mkdir /var/mysql
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

This worked instantly and no changes to PHP or Git-able files.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This the definitely the right way of doing it. Thanks Jamie.

I was using the above method earlier, where i had to always change the setting back to normal on my production server.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel Framework 5.7 Installation on Mac os with MAMP**

**Composer**
Composer installation

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

**Installing laravel**

1. composer global require laravel/installer
2. PATH=$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin
3. laravel new

chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache

## After i got 500 error

checked error log found following error

```
tail -f /Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log
```

Found :syntax error, unexpected '=' `blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 388`

I changed my php version 7.1  solved my problem